# Secret Folders in Git

Tags: git

I want to know if there is a way to store some specific files in a Git repository for only some specific users. For example, I wanted to store a template of my program's UI and I wanted it to be accessible only by me. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: No. (It's not possible)

Comment: The answer is "sort of". There are a variety of solutions for storing encrypted data in your git repository ([sops](https://github.com/mozilla/sops), [ansible vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html), just plain-old [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/), etc), but they're all hacks that suffer from the same problem: in the event of a key compromise, you're screwed, because you can't retroactively change the keys in your git repository once people have cloned it. If you need secure storage, put the files somewhere else (e.g., a private repository).

Comment: Use a different repo to hold the _private_ part that only some user will be able to access..... though that does not mean that they won't be able to push into a public repo.... just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git itself doesn't do permissions on directory or branch level. If you have a branch containing commits that you want nobody to see, you have two options:

1. Never push it anywhere and keep it only on your local PC. This requires you to keep manual backups
2. Create a private repository on a server and push your changes there. Make sure that access permissions are set up correctly.